# How to add subplots to a dynamic plot with pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have never used pyplot and I'm new to python (using 2.7.3) and I've tried a couple of ways to try to add 2 subplots to the following class, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.  I've tried a few references like http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html and http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html
 but I'm not familiar with the syntax these demos use or how to expand it to the class I've modified.

I need something to work more dynamically so I can add to the dataset and replot as needed.  Here's my basic class to handle plot

```
class PlotTrades(object):
    '''Plot and save graph of Prices vs Buy/Sell'''
    def __init__(self, pair):
        self.pair = pair
        self.graph = pylab.figure()
        pylab.rcParams.update({'legend.labelspacing': 0.25,
                               'legend.fontsize': 'x-small'})
        self.tradeCount = 0;
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        self.toPlot = {}
        self.toPlot['price'] = {'label': 'Price', 'color': 'k', 'style': '-'}

    def append(self, line, value):
        '''Append new point to specified line['values'] in toPlot dict'''
        self.toPlot[line].setdefault('values', []).append(value)
        self.toPlot[line].setdefault('count', []).append(self.tradeCount)

    def updatePlot(self):
        '''Clear, re-draw, and save.
        Allows viewing "real-time" as an image
        '''
        self.tradeCount += 1

        # clear figure and axes
        pylab.clf()
        pylab.cla()
        pylab.grid(True, axis='y', linewidth=1, color='gray', linestyle='--')
        # plot each line
        pylab.plot(self.toPlot['price'].get('count'), self.toPlot['price'].get('values'), label='Price', color='k',
                   linestyle='-')

        pylab.ylim([0,10])
        # labels
        # legend top-left
        pylab.legend(loc=2)
        # save and close
        pylab.savefig('trade_graph.png')
        pylab.close(self.graph)
```

This code is for one plot, how would I break it into 3?  I would like to add a 2 subplots with data not yet shown in this code.  I understand that I need to use subplot and layout the plots, but how do I associate the correct datasets with each plot?

A push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: can you reduce the cruft so it is easier to see what you code is doing?  (ex setting the limits in not relevant to your question)

Comment: @tcaswell no problem.  I've removed some of the extra code.

Comment: Just add `pylab.subplot(131)` before the first plot statement, 132 before the second plot statement, and finally 133.

Comment: Or use `fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)`. Example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html